# PICAXE blinking an LED causes small spike in another signal path

Tags: led, picaxe

[image: Stompbox circuit]

I have the circuit below which I designed.  The problem I'm having is that when I blink the LED (by setting B.4 [pin 9] alternately high and low), I'm measuring a roughly 4mV (relative to ground) 400uS long spike on pin 4 of K4 (yes, the relay pin that is open) each time the voltage transitions. I don't see anything on the +5 rails. What could be causing this and how do I fix it?

Comment: why is it a problem?

Comment: It's a problem because the path through the relay is audio at microphone level, so 4mV is significant.

Comment: How are you making the measurement that shows the spike - I guess with an oscilloscope? Is the scope ground floating relative to the circuit power supply or do they share a ground, and where in the circuit are you making the ground connection? What is the audio signal coming from and going to, and have you seen this effect with the source and destination connected?

Comment: Incidentally, it looks as if you're using a relay to switch between two bi-colour LEDs - is there any reason for that, rather than just driving the four LEDs individually as you seem to have pins spare? Also your serial input circuit on pin 2 is not correct - see page 8 of [the manual](https://picaxe.com/docs/picaxe_manual1.pdf).

Comment: The project was originally conceived for an 08M2 so pins were at a premium and I never readjusted my thinking.  And you're right, the serial in is incorrect, I've fixed it on the schematic.  (It wasn't populated on the board)

Answer (score 1):

I know this is not your exact circuit, but the [PICAXE-14 Project Board (AXE117)](https://picaxe.com/docs/axe117.pdf) has the following picture,
[image]

and the following schematic:

[image]

which to me suggests that you should have a 100nF polyester capacitor bypassing your PicAxe, yet you show none in your schematic. [This one](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/kemet/R82DC3100DQ50J/1930798) should work.

You may also need capacitors around your voltage regulator (7805).

[image]

Look up the datasheet to find out. [This datasheet](https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/l78l.pdf) is for this [ST Microelectronics comparable part](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/stmicroelectronics/L78L05ABZ-TR/1038272).

And it looks like your voltage regulator is only made for 100mA, but the 1K in line with your LED (though you don't mention the color) should not be causing a problem there, but the relays might be drawing more than that. So measure all your currents and voltages.

If you still can't figure it out, try removing (physically and/or electrically) from the circuit one by one, starting with the unused relay. Process of elimination will get you far.